# Error running SSIS Package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssis

I found a similar problem to mine : [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/133872/error-updating-ssis-package-to-2014-due-to-script-component/133969)
 .

The issue I'm having:

I have a package(SSDT 15), and in the beginning of it I have a `Script component` that dynamically set up my variables.

I made a web application with c# on VS17 that runs a procedure, that runs the package with input parameters.

When I manually run the procedure \ the package, everything works fine. But when I run the package through the web application, I'm getting an error :

> Define Connections:Error: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ComponentVersionMismatchException: The version of Load Connections is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.  [[The version or pipeline version or both for the specified component is higher than the current version.  This package was probably created on a new version of DTS or the component than is installed on the current PC.]]

I tried editing my script component to use framework 3.5 instead of 4.5 , but it just ruin every reference and doesn't help me.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You have a web application in C# that calls a procedure that calls an SSIS package that runs a C# script. That is definitely too complicated. What are you really trying to do? I'm sure it doesn't need to be so complicated (complicated = prone to failure, difficult to maintain and debug)

Comment: It does need to be this complicated because of privacy matters. I created a dynamic procedure that accept parameters and run an SSIS package dynamically using the `start_execution` command. The users are not allowed to get access to the DB it is stored in, but need to be able to run a specific package with this procedure. Therefore - the web application which will be available for these users to accept input parameters @Nick.McDermaid Have I missed anything?

Comment: Can the package functionality functionality just be included inside the database? anyway back to your original error, I can only guess that the package version is different to the ssis catalog version or something like that. This might help: https://sqlstudies.com/2015/04/27/what-sql-version-is-my-ssis-package/

Comment: Nope, that's why I made this "complicated" . Though I find it very easy(as long as it works haha) . This design allows me to put many services and many packages (and I don't mean scheduled ones , but those that run with parameters) online, and to determine who can use which.

Comment: In regard to the question, the duplicate + your link helped me solve the issue :) thanks. @Nick.McDermaid